# Delphi XE8 omit all break points in some units and display "Error setting debug exception hook."

Tags: debugging, delphi, delphi-xe8

I have an app developed in Delphi XE8 which suddenly start behaving very strange.

The first problem is that any break points are omitted on compile (green lines). So practically I can't put any break point at all.

The second problem (probably result from the first one) - not always, but on every third compile a error message is displayed "Error setting debug exception hook.".

I've tested with Delphi 11 and also break-points are omitted, so I suppose it is something in the project itself, however I've tried with some back-ups from several years ago that always has been working, now there also same problem occurs.

Can any one help, please. Without ability to debug its almost impossible to develop the app.

UPDATE: I tested different ways to solve this. And the same project debug correctly on my laptop. Also some units keeps their break points, while others don't. Also tried a preinstall of Delphi XE8 - the problem still persist.

Thank you,
Georgi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. It was in the ***Project Options --> Delphi Compiler --> Output directory.*** The output directory was correct, but for some reason the value from *"All configurations - All platforms"* (in the drop-down) was pointing to very old non-existing folder. Making it the same as the main Output path solved the problem and the debugger is not "confused" anymore what to debug.
Still a mystery is why with the same options at my laptop everything was working fine (the folder was not existing there too).